# Solr More Like This (MLT) not returning results

Tags: solr, django-haystack, morelikethis, pysolr

I'm currently looking to implement more like this functionality based on a on a number of fields in my index.

My current configuration is as follows:
Haystack | PySolr | Solr

For this piece I'm using PySolr and passing the parameters to the more_like_this function.  The response finds the document but not any related results.  Why is that?

Here is the URL I hit:

> ```
> http://localhost:8080/solr/mlt?q=django_id:12123412&mlt.fl=industry_ids,loc_state,amount,sector_id&mlt.interestingTerms=details
> ```

Here is my response from Solr:

```
<response>
<object type="{XXXXXX-0F1D-4F28-AAA2-XXXXXXXXXXX}" cotype="cs" id="cosymantecbfw" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: block;"/>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">24</int>
</lst>
<result name="match" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>...</doc>
</result>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
<lst name="interestingTerms"/>
</response>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<!-- More Like This -->
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
</requestHandler>
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="award_amount" type="sfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" />
<field name="estatus" type="slong" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="loc_state" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="orgtype_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" />
<field name="sector_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="industry_ids" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" />
<field name="award_amount_exact" type="sfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" />
<field name="sector_id_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="amount_exact" type="sfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your text fields must have type `text`, which processes them to make them **searchable**. The `string` fields are stored and queried as they are, so **they are not searchable**, making them useless for MLT.

Refer *copy fields* if you ever want to store the same data as both `text` and `string` (for example, faceting).

---

I see you also intend to find numbers closest to our query. MLT is not right for that. You want to compose a **function query** for that. [SolR : More Like This on number fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243109/solr-more-like-this-on-number-fields)

Comment: I realized that my mlt.mintf and mlt.mindf settings were to high which prevented me from receiving results.